# Integration of characteristic function with varying boundaries

Tags: integration, analysis, limits, functions

I'm a bit puzzled about integrals with indicator/characteristic functions in them. How do I start computing the following integrals?
$$
A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\chi_{[-a+x,a+x]}dx
$$
and
$$
A\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)\chi_{[-a+x,a+x]}dx
$$
In these integrals, $A$ is just a function that doesn't matter, a is a parameter value determined already (could be 2 for example), $x$ runs over the real axis and $f(x)$ is a function where assumptions can be made (so you may impose quadratic integrability if it would lead to a solution).

Any help would be greatly appreciated appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \geq 0$ then $\chi_{[-a+x,a+x]}(x) = 1$ for all $x$ since $x \in [-a+x,a+x]$.  The first integral is just

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx
$$

and the second is

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} xf(x)\,dx.
$$